# Readonly wrapper of a LinkedList. HowTo?

Tags: .net, list, .net-2.0, readonly

.NET v2

When the List has a very useful (4 me) method AsReadOnly()
the LinkedList does not have such a method.

Is there a way to "quickly" interface an internal *LinkedList* to read only from the external code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` takes an `IList<T>` as argument to the constructor. `LinkedList<T>` does not implement this interface. `List<T>` has a constructor overload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as argument, and `LinkedList<T>` implements this interface. So the following should work:

```
LinkedList<int> linked = new LinkedList<int>();
// populate the list

ReadOnlyCollection<int> readOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(
    new List<int>(linked));
```

It uses an instance of `List<T>` to carry the items into the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` constructor.

Comment: *grumble something about wanting a readonly `LinkedList` not `IList`* (the question, not the answer)

Comment: For an unknown reason `LinkedListNode` is sealed and `LinkedList` has no virtual methods so you're stuck to writing your own doubly linked list with immutable nodes

Answer (score 9):

Why not just return a `IEnumerable<T>`? If you just want to let users enumerate the list without modifying it*, IEnumerable is the obvious choice.

If you want to have a read only interface of the LinkedList interface, you can wrap LinkedList, forward read only methods to the wrapped list and deny any changes.

*) Keep in mind that neither ReadOnlyCollection not IEnumerable will prevent callers to change state of objects in case of a collection of reference types. If the objects should be read only as well, you need to implement this as part of their type.

Comment: I assume you want to return a readonly version of your LinkedList. You can do this by returning it as an IEnumerable<T>. This will allow the caller to enumerate the list, but not to modify it.

Comment: If those methods are important, then you have to wrap LinkedList and basically do what ReadOnlyCollection does.

Comment: You have reason. Unfortunately I not have experience in creating wrappers or what ReadOnlyCollection does. So a little sample would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## #1 Fix the Linked List

```
class FixedLinkedList<T> : LinkedList<T>, IList<T>
{
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetAt(index).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            GetAt(index).Value = value;
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var node = First;
        while (node!= null && !node.Value.Equals(item))
        {
            i++;
            node = node.Next;
        }

        if (node == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        AddBefore(GetAt(index), new LinkedListNode<T>(item));
    }


    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        Remove(GetAt(index));
    }

    private LinkedListNode<T> GetAt(int index)
    {
        CheckIndex(index);
        int i = 0;
        var node = First;
        while (i < index)
        {
            i++;
            node = node.Next;
        }

        return node;
    }

    private void CheckIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                nameof(index),
                "Parameter must be greater or equal to 0.");
        }

        if (index >= Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                nameof(index),
                "Parameter must be lower than the list item Count.");
        }
    }
}
```

## #2 Wraps its instances in ReadOnlyCollection

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList<T>` doesn't implement `IList` so in short, no there is no way of quickly doing it. If you cast your LinkedList to a List you will probably lose the functionality you require.

`LinkedList<T>` doesn't offer you anything for subclassing so you'll need to write your own. I imagine the next request is "can you show me how to do that"

Comment: Is returning a list ok? Or do you need it to be a `LinkedList`

Comment: I'd prefeer a *Linked* Readonly List